# How to filter an observable object in ionic 4 / angular 7?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, filter, observable

I am reading in a json array and then sending it back to several functions as an observable.  I am trying to filter this is two of the functions, but it's not working and it's returning a null value.

What is the correct way to filter this?

I've tried several different ways of returning it but it always return nulls.

This one returns all the data and actually works

```
    console.log('getMenu1');
    return this.http.get('../../assets/data/hospitals.json').pipe(
        map(results => results['hospitals'])
    );
  }
```

This one of the functions that should filter the name based on a search string, but it doesn't work.... always get null

```
getFilteredHospitals1(text: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('getMenu1');
    let searchText = text.toLowerCase();
    return this.http.get('../../assets/data/hospitals.json').pipe(
        map(results => results['hospitals'].filter(res => res.name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > 0 ) )
    );
  }
```

This is supposed to return an exact match for the id, but it doesn't work - also null.

```
getHospitalByID(id: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('getHospitalByID = ' + id);
    let searchText = id.toLowerCase();
    console.log('getHospitalByID = ' + searchText);
    return this.http.get('../../assets/data/hospitals.json').pipe(
        map(results => results['hospitals'].filter(res => res.id === searchText ) )
    );
  }
```

This is the json file it's reading

```
{
  "hospitals": [ {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Lehigh Valley Hospital-Cedar Crest",
    "address": "1200 South Cedar Crest Blvd, Allentown, PA 18105",
    "website": "www.lvhn.org",
    "trauma": "Level I",
    "peds": "Level II",
    "stroke": "Comprehensive",
    "ebola": "No",
    "phone": "610-402-8000",
    "special": "Special Annodote",
    "speciallink": "www.lvhn.org"
  },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Lehigh Valley Hospital-17th Street",
      "address": "17th and Chew Sts, Allentown, PA 18105",
      "website": "www.lvhn.org",
      "trauma": "N/A",
      "peds": "N/A",
      "stroke": "N/A",
      "ebola": "No",
      "phone": "610-969-2388",
      "special": "Special Annodote",
      "speciallink": "www.lvhn.org"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Lehigh Valley Hospital-Mulenberg",
      "address": "2545 Schoenersville Rd, Bethlehem, PA 18017",
      "website": "www.lvhn.org",
      "trauma": "N/A",
      "peds": "N/A",
      "stroke": "Primary",
      "ebola": "Yes",
      "phone": "610-402-8000",
      "special": "Special Annodote",
      "speciallink": "www.lvhn.org"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Lehigh Valley Hospital-Hazleton",
      "address": "700 East Broad St, Hazleton, PA 18201",
      "website": "hazleton.lvhn.org",
      "trauma": "N/A",
      "peds": "N/A",
      "stroke": "Primary",
      "ebola": "No",
      "phone": "570-501-4000",
      "special": "Special Annodote",
      "speciallink": "www.lvhn.org"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's where it's being called

````
   ngOnInit() {
    // Get the ID that was passed with the URL
    let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    console.log('Details');

    this.hospitalService.getHospitalByID(id).subscribe(result => {
      this.information = result;
    });

    console.log(this.information);
  }```

Unfortunately, the two "search" functions always return null.  The first function works.
````

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code.

The `indexOf(searchText) > 0` have two errors. You should ensure that `searchText` also is lower case by using `searchText.toLowerCase()`. You also need to change from `0` to `-1` since it otherwise would miss a search string that's in the beginning of the searched text.

The `getHospitalByID` function works for me when I test it, see [this working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwd3ql) app.

Comment: I actually did figure it out but I don't have enough room in my comment to share the code sorry.